Bias Omni Navigation Towards Forward Movement
I am working on an omnidirectional robot using ROS2 and NAV2 BT navigator stack. I have managed to get the lattice planner working and have full omni directional movement. I was wondering if there was any way to bias the existing planner or the DWBLocalPlanner towards forward (+X) movement when possible and to only consider Y movement when necessary (Ex: not enough space to turn around)
Appreciate any insight thanks!

See the DWB / MPPI critics, they both have forward preferenced critics built in.

Thanks for the tip, I added the ForwardPath critic and started tuning the PathAlign Scaling aswell.
Something else I've noticed is that the planner seems to go straight untill it finds a right angle corner and then faces the corner and almost turns around the corner like its a pivot point and then afterwards continues to go straight.
Does this sound familiar at all?
